# How to make the keep mine strategy with git?

Tags: git

I'm configuring a webserver and I'm using git to get the updated files into the server. My problem is that I have a config file where I put the connection string, base url, etc... I want git to always keep my version of the file, and I don't want it to update with the file from the git repository.

How to I do that in the linux command line?

Comment: Better way will be to have two different files: for example config.global and config.local and prepare a function to somehow merge its contents or overwrite - depending the structure of your file. Then only put your .global file to git and the .local one add to .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is saved in the repo and you have local changes and then you checkout another commit, it wont overwrite your local changes, so it should persist (provided you haven't specified -f to the checkout command). Or is this in regards to a git merge? (the "keep mine" that you mention in the title).

If its a merge and you don't really want to merge one file, you can do a merge with --no-commit and then overwrite the file that you don't want to change with the version you want to persist and then do the commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can push your version of the file, which will stay in the repository, clone repo, modify your file and do:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged file.conf`, which will mark your file as untracked. You can modify it, do `git status` and see it's not listed.

You can also try doing the same, but then adding the file to .gitignore, it will automatically ignore it from all changes in all local repositories. Such file you can still re-track with `git add --force file.conf`, not sure which will work better for you.